# Are federal employees bound to report fraud and cyber crime they've been made aware of?

Tags: united-states, us-federal-government

To what degree are federal employees of the executive branch (such as members of the FBI, CISA, NSA, and CIA) bound by law or otherwise to report illegal activities pertaining to tech crimes, fraud (civil and criminal), and classified information that they are made aware of during their everyday activities.

For one of many possible hypothetical scenarios, let's say they knew someone had compromised a government computer system and was determined to release classified information, or *had already done do*. Do they have any additional obligation to report this.

In their daily lives, may these employees disregard what they learn of and decline to report evidence of potential offences to the government? Or, are they bound by "mandatory reporting" laws because of their official capacity and job duty?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151306/discussion-on-question-by-evan-carroll-are-federal-employees-bound-to-report-fra); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.